# Ubuntu 16.04: Internet Is Not Functioning Properly (RTL8821AE)

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, realtek

I'm still very new to Linux and I'm still trying to set up the basics to get everything working properly. Right now the only thing I need to do is get my wireless internet working properly. I've been looking around for ages but I've yet to actually try anything as I simply don't know what it will do.

The driver I currently have is RTL8821AE for Realtek.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your router to Legacy mode like its explained here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1526683